# Save a has_one model with a nested form with Devise - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

I'm stuck in a rails project trying to save a has_one model when the user signs up with Devise.

My app is saving the child model as well as the new user but the issue is that it doesn't save the child id in the user table.

I've tried plenty of options found on Stackoverflow without success. 
Am I doing something wrong?

**User model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:linkedin]

  # Associations
  has_one :build, inverse_of: :user
  # Allow saving of attributes on associated records through the parent,
# :autosave option is automatically enabled on every association
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :build, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**build model**

```
class Build < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :build
  has_one :template
  # validates_presence_of :user
end
```

**Registrations Controller**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
before_action :sign_up_params, only: [:create]
before_action :account_update_params, only: [:update]
# before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    # super

    # Override Devise default behaviour and create a build as well
    build_resource({})
    resource.build_build
    respond_with self.resource

    # @build = @user.builds.build(template_id: params[:template_id], domain_url: params[:domain_url])
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
    # @build = current_user.build.build(params[:post])

    # @build = @user.build.build(template_id: sign_up_params[:template_id], domain_url: sign_up_params[:domain_url])
    # @build.save
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver unless @user.invalid?
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  # protected
  #
  # def configure_permitted_parameters
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
  #     u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :builds_attributes => [:template_id, :domain_url])
  #   }
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # The path used after sign up.
  # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  private

  def sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_up)
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, build_attributes: [:template_id, :domain_url])
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

**New User Form - View**

```
<div class="container">
<h4 class="center-align">Sign up</h4>

<div id="signup-row" class="row z-depth-2">
    <div id="signup" class="col s6">

        <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <%= devise_error_messages! %>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :first_name %><br/>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :last_name %><br/>
            <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :email %><br/>
            <%= f.email_field :email %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <% if @minimum_password_length %>
            <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %>
                characters minimum)</em>
            <% end %><br/>
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br/>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'btn black' %>
            <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

        </div>

        <%= f.fields_for :build do |o| %>
      <%= o.hidden_field :template_id, value: params["template"] %>
      <%= o.hidden_field :domain_url, value: params["domain"] %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <div id="linkedin-signup" class="col s6">
      <div class="center-align">
        <h5>Sign up with LinkedIn </h5> <br>
        <a href="http://localhost:3000/login/li/oauth2"><%= image_tag('linkedin.png', :class => "linkedIn-logo" ) %></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

**Server /post log**

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-03 13:31:22 +1000
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"11DgWCU07EXLJKXbhWah0gREdBiN2PLkF/WxWsuqW5rgQdCUrRH9rLBrKpbusRhtsCzSAQT0ADlxhQxMvWAD6A==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"john", "last_name"=>"maksksk", "email"=>"jofff@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "build_attributes"=>{"template_id"=>"1", "domain_url"=>"dddddd.com.au"}}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'jofff@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["first_name", "john"], ["last_name", "maksksk"], ["email", "jofff@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$WgJJ.uM2DfaqQhUYatUZnuIJmaqIDVfIuYEkl/U3zSbm.h/OH/yGa"], ["created_at", "2016-08-03 03:31:22.796589"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-03 03:31:22.796589"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "builds" ("template_id", "domain_url", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["template_id", 1], ["domain_url", "dddddd.com.au"], ["user_id", 30], ["created_at", "2016-08-03 03:31:22.800033"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-03 03:31:22.800033"]]
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "last_sign_in_ip" = $3, "current_sign_in_ip" = $4, "sign_in_count" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "users"."id" = $7  [["last_sign_in_at", "2016-08-03 03:31:22.804259"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2016-08-03 03:31:22.804259"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1/32"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1/32"], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["updated_at", "2016-08-03 03:31:22.805380"], ["id", 30]]
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
```

Thanks for your help!!

ps: build wasn't a smart name for a table I guess...

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that user saved first and then you saved build for relationship purpose you can save user_id to build table instead of saving build_id to user**

Comment: Thanks. That might be it. Any idea on how I can save it all at once?

Comment: You are keeping your real model suspense and asking answer you need to share all three models and what you want to achieve clearly. Then I might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, build_attributes: [:id, :template_id, :domain_url])
```

build_attributes should has `:id`

making a test

```
def create
  user = User.new(sign_up_params)
  user.save
end
```

Comment: Thanks Breno.
However, it doesn't work as it doesn't get the id from the form. I think it saves the user first and doesn't have the build id.

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Atu7B4voCs8T1Rtz82zc3MRABSUfqQa9374ogg1WVBL5W0Kicc9DLrigggOuVJL+rb0FXjHJ5Yu5Bvfo05+NXA==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"ophk", "last_name"=>"kddkd", "email"=>"kjiuh@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "build_attributes"=>{"template_id"=>"1", "domain_url"=>"khljgjjff.com"}}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}`

Comment: But insert a binding.pry ou debug to verify 'user.errors' to identify the object build has created or with errors

Comment: Using binding.pry is nice idea but what is problem is already konwn. Problem is that user saved first and then build but he wants build id in user table. Which is not possible.

Comment: I remembered a one thing when I had created model with name build I had also a problem. I have change to builder. I think that word build is reserved word

Comment: In nested association you can create a new user with new association build and if run action save in the first association the nested will created the build after created user.

Comment: hum that's a nice thought. I will try to change the model name

Answer (score 0):

model User.rb

```
has_one :build
accepts_nested_attributes_for :build, allow_destroy: true
```

rails console

```
user  = User.new(name: 'example', build_attributes:{template_id:1, domain_url: 'test'})

user.save # this will create user and after that will create has_one build association
user.errors unless user.save
```